# Is there anything that automatically appends &IsDlg=0 to URL's?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, url, modal-dialog

We have some custom master pages and coded pages that generate URL's to lead to the profile pages and the log out page, however in some of the Blog pages that we have the Profile and Log Out page links append &IsDlg=0 to the URL's.  Within our code there doesn't seem to be anything that is adding this, and we don't utilize the Dialog's much on our site, so I am at a loss as to where this might be coming from.  Is there are sort of behind the scenes SharePoint process that might add this onto specific pages?  The only place this seems to happen is within the community/blog/itemview.aspx page.

If there isn't anything does anyone have any ideas as to where this might be coming from that I can diagnose the issue?  While it generally doesn't have an effect, within the profile page, the Log Out directs the browser to the main page which then is only partially shown due to the Dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to List or Library Settings > Advanced Settings and scroll to the bottom you'll see a setting to launch forms in a dialog. I believe the value of this setting controls the addition of IsDlg=[0,1] to the query string.

Comment: Ah, I see that although it ended up being some behind the scenes code that was getting imported through another library.  I'm definitely going to check this first next time though, thanks!